# Accept all out of date self-signed certificates

Tags: windows, ssl, webserver, certificate

My work computer does not access the internet at all, ever. We have a web server that has an out of date certificate that is preventing me from accessing it programmatically with a POST request.

I would like to just use the nuke option and trust all certificates regardless if they are out of date or not.  Is there an easy way to do this windows 7?

Comment: How exactly are you performing the POST?

Comment: Download each certificate and place it in the machine certificate store.  Doing so will require you be an Administrator on the Active Domain

Comment: @Ramhound I added it to the Trusted Root Certification Authority.  Is this the equivalent?  Would it make sense that even if the certificate is verified it still would not like it because it is out of date?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I'm making the POST request through an R package, httr. https://github.com/hadley/httr

Comment: You should be able to add code to accept the certificate programmattically.